# Como redirecionar questão "q=" de um site para outro sem alterar a pergunta?

Tags: jquery, htaccess

Tenho um mini site de pesquisa: `http://www.cosmo-search.url.ph`, e quando for digitado

```
www.cosmo-search.url.ph/search?q=PESQUISA-FEITA-PELO-USUÁRIO
```

preciso que seja redirecionado para

```
br.search.yahoo.com/yhs/search?p=PESQUISA-FEITA-PELO-USUÁRIO&hspart=Ballooninc&hsimp=yhs-selfserve_5414a9bb52031219
```

seguindo o exemplo do 22find, que quando solicitado `"http://www.22find.com/web?q=PESQUISA"`, é redirecionado para `search.yahoo.com/search?q=PESQUISA`.

Answer (score 2):

Para ir buscar a query string pode usar:

```
location.search.slice(3)
```

Depois só tem de concatenar essa string no url que tem:

```
var string = location.search.slice(3);
var novoUrl = ['br.search.yahoo.com/yhs/search?p=', string,'&hspart=Ballooninc&hsimp=yhs-selfserve_5414a9bb52031219'].join('');
window.location = novoUrl;
```

Na primeira linha vai buscar o endereço atual, com a querystring e retirando-lhe o `?q=`.
Na segunda linha gera uma nova string com combinando com o url que pretende.
Na terceira linha faz o re-direct.

#### Para usar isso no seu site pode fazer assim:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var string = document.getElementById('#search-box').value;
    var novoUrl = ['br.search.yahoo.com/yhs/search?p=', string, '&hspart=Ballooninc&hsimp=yhs-selfserve_5414a9bb52031219'].join('');
    window.location = novoUrl;
};
```

Comment: Desculpe, eu estava ocupado. E como eu aplico este no form?

Comment: <form method="get" action="https://br.search.yahoo.com/yhs/search">
    <input id="search-box" name="p" type="text" autofocus value="" autocomplete="off"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="hspart" name="hspart" value="Ballooninc">
    <input type="hidden" id="hsimp" name="hsimp" value="yhs-selfserve_5414a9bb52031219">
    <input type="image" src="buttons/submit.png" value="">
</form>

Comment: Agora pouquinho topei com este snippet para puxar todas as vars da query: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21152762

Comment: @GustavoBarbosa se quer fazer isto via cliente (javascript) entao nao deve submeter o form. Deve parar o submit e fazer o redirect sem passar pelo servidor. É isso que quer?

Comment: Quero fazer com que a página /search do meu servidor redirecione a pesquisa para o Yahoo. Ex: Clique no link e veja: http://www.22find.com/web?q=suapesquisa

Comment: @GustavoBarbosa, teste adicionar esse código que juntei agora à resposta no final da sua página. Antes do `</body>`